# Поиск суммы чисел из списка, не превышающих значение, питон

Tags: python

новичок в PY.
Хочу написать следующий кусок кода:
есть некие значения, например:
5 124 543 261 14 535 525
и есть конкретное число, например 1432

Цель: найти максимальное количество значений, которые в сумме дают максимально близкое значение к 1432, но не переходят за него. Ну и нужно, чтобы этих значений в сложении было как можно больше. То есть, имеем числа 1 4 3 2 4, нужно дойти до числа 10, или около него.
Нужно, чтобы скрипт вывел не 4+4+2, а 1+2+3+4, т.к. в последнем случае чисел больше.

Но даже в голову не приходит идея реализации.

Comment: Честно, не понял. Что вот это значит: максимальное количество значений, которые в сумме дают максимально близкое значение.

Comment: Отсортируйте значения от меньших к большим и пробуйте подбирать варианты с меньших чисел